# howto in eclipse debug the Proguard obfuscated apk file

Tags: android, proguard

I got a crash in my app after using Proguard and signing and exporting with a new key.
The same code works in normal eclipse debug mode.

I read everywhere i should use the mapping.txt to find the code that failed.
But how to do that, I have google this for 2 hour now and no answer is working.

Im now signing the apk file with the debug.keystore and using the default password "android".
Someone say i should android:debuggable="false" in my application tag to make
Proguard obfuscate my debug session in eclipse.

Is this right?
Any help would be grate

on the [Proguard Android Developer page](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html) I cannot find a way to do this

"When your obfuscated code outputs a stack trace, the method names are obfuscated, which makes debugging ha"

What "stack trace" and from where?

On the page [Proguard  Manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) I cannot find an explanation

Comment: Not sure if this is right, Im exporting Android application the signed (debug.keystore) app to the "bin" folder and replacing the app file there. I press F11 and and it looks like it's about to start a debug session. The message "Wating for debugger" will however not go away.
Manifest debuggable=true and permission android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP is there to. Is this the way to do it?

Comment: Im exporting Android application the signed (debug.keystore) app to the "bin" folder and replacing the app file there. I press F11 and i can run the apk on the emulator only. Now, in the LogCat i see the exceptions just like normal. Does this mean that im debugging the obfuscated apk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not within Eclipse.

Outside of Eclipse, use `Retrace` function within ProGuard. You'll also need the dumped stacktrace and `mapping.txt` found under your project's `proguard` directory to reverse the obfuscated stacktrace. Remember to save a copy of `mapping.txt` (preferably outside of your project's workspace) each time you deploy a new version of your Android app.

Answer (score 8):

You can de-obfuscate the stack trace most easily using the Proguard GUI. You'll find this with your Android SDK.

```
sdk\tools\proguard\bin\proguardgui.bat
```

1. Run the GUI above from the path above.
2. Click the 'ReTrace' button at the bottom of the panel on the left.
3. Add the path to your Mapping File (mapping.txt) in the 'Mapping file' text box.
4. Paste a copy of your stack trace in the 'Obfuscated stack trace' text box.
5. Click 'ReTrace' in the bottom right.
6. Happy Debugging!

[image]

Comment: Grrrrrr8 will Calderwood:)

Answer (score 4):

Been looking into this, the documentation for proguard on the android developer site demonstrates how to decode a stack trace, but it does not specify how to get the stack trace.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html (see section Decoding Obfuscated Stack Traces)

I tried to use a logcat dump as follows:-

```
E/AndroidRuntime(14584): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime(14584): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

E/AndroidRuntime(14584):    at com.a.a.b.a.dg.<init>(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(14584):    at com.a.a.b.a.q.a(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(14584):    at com.a.a.b.a.y.a(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(14584):    at com.a.a.b.a.y.a(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(14584):    at com.a.a.b.a.aq.get(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(14584):    at com.a.a.b.cp.a(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(14584):    at com.a.a.b.ai.c(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(14584):    at com.a.a.b.bg.a(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(14584):    at com.a.a.a.o.a(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(14584):    at com.a.a.b.ee.a(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(14584):    at com.a.a.b.ag.a(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(14584):    at com.a.a.b.cb.a(Unknown Source)
```

Unfortunately this does not work, but it does work if I remove the E/AndroidRuntime(14584) from the beginning of each line it does work:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.a.a.b.a.dg.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.a.a.b.a.q.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.a.a.b.a.y.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.a.a.b.a.y.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.a.a.b.a.aq.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.a.a.b.cp.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.a.a.b.ai.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.a.a.b.bg.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.a.a.a.o.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.a.a.b.ee.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.a.a.b.ag.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.a.a.b.cb.a(Unknown Source)
```

So as the documentation states you need a stack trace file, and there appears to be no indication of getting a valid stack trace file from the device.

The only way I have seen this done is by providing a custom exception handler and writing the stack trace to the sdcard.

Comment: If you don't want to write an exception handler yourself, use a third-party, tried-and-tested, error-reporting Java library for Android like ACRA (See [here](http://acra.ch/) for more info).

Answer (score 1):

For mac user use bellow code to run the 
/Users/XYZ/Library/Android/sdk/tools/proguard/bin/proguardgui.sh

1. Run the GUI above from the path above.
2. Click the 'ReTrace' button at the bottom of the panel on the left.
3. Add the path to your Mapping File (mapping.txt) in the 'Mapping
   file' text box.
4. Paste a copy of  your stack trace in the 'Obfuscated stack trace'
   text box. Click
5. 'ReTrace' in the bottom right.

Happy Debugging!

Answer (score -5):

### Steps to get obfuscated apk:

1. Download latest proguard from [proguard site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/). Current latest version is proguard4.7
2. Replace "bin" and "lib" folder of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\proguard` with latest downloaded proguard folders.
3. Check SDK location in eclipse for blank spaces in it and for that go to Window > Preferences > Android. If there is blank space then replace it with:

   ```
   c:\Progra~2\android\android-sdk (for windows 64-bit)
   c:\Progra~1\android\android-sdk (for windows 32-bit)
   ```
4. Check that proguard.cfg file is in your project's root folder and add `proguard.config=proguard.cfg` in project.properties file of android project.
5. Now export your project to get obfuscated apk.

Comment: The question isn't asking how to get the an obfuscated apk, but how to debug one. It seems the user has already done this (getting the obfuscated apk), and is having trouble working with the results.